# Xamarin.iOS remote build unable to connect

Tags: xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.ios, msbuild

I am using Jenkins for my Xamarin (iOS) builds. There are two build jobs, one of which works every time I run it and the other stopped working a week ago. Both build configurations are nearly identical.

#### Working build

```
msbuild mySolution.sln /t:restore /t:myIOSProject /p:Configuration="Release" /p:ServerAddress="XXX.XXX.XXX.XX" /p:ServerUser="adminUser" /p:ServerPassword=AdminPassword /p:Platform="iPhone"
```

#### "Broken" build

```
msbuild mySolution.sln /t:restore /t:myIOSProject /p:Configuration="Release" /p:ServerAddress="XXX.XXX.XXX.XX" /p:ServerUser="adminUser" /p:ServerPassword=AdminPassword /p:Platform="iPhone" /p:IpaPackageDir="%USERPROFILE%\Builds"
```

The broken build stops working with the following message:

> Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(81,3): warning : There is no connection
>   to the Mac, the task
>   Xamarin.Messaging.Tasks.CopyFileFromMac will not be executed.

I had to translate the message because my build configuration is not in english. At this point the build does not fail or anything, it just hangs at this point forever.

As you can see the only difference between the above configurations is the output folder for the ipa file (`/p:IpaPackageDir`).

#### Important

Once I remove the output folder option in the broken build, the build works fine again.

#### What I tried

1. Killing mono via `killall mono` on the Mac
2. Deleting `$HOME/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA` and `$HOME/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs`.

What could be the reason for the problem? The problem seems to have occured out of nowhere, I did not temper with the Mac or my build system.

Comment: Is that your shell file or yaml file. Could you share a bit more of it? Could you also try doing an `ls` and changing directory to see if you actually have access to any directory with that name `%USERPROFILE%\Builds`. Try to do an `ls %USERPROFILE%` and see if it returns anything in the output

Comment: Is this what you were trying to follow? https://github.com/INaCloud/Xamarin-Docs/blob/4c302db5486815acb11f62a1ef8e72f615a5f582/docs/tools/ci/includes/commandline-compile-of-xamarin-ios-ipa.md or https://github.com/INaCloud/Xamarin-Docs/blob/4c302db5486815acb11f62a1ef8e72f615a5f582/docs/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support.md . It seems like you should be using `/p:IpaPackageDir="%USERPROFILE%\Builds"` for a Windows runner and `/p:IpaPackageDir="$HOME/Builds"` for a Mac runner